# writing and reading an array of integers from a binary file

Tags: c, file, loops, while-loop, binary

Hi there I am trying to write and read an array of integers from a file, However, The loop that I am using to read them back is in an infinite loop. How would I fix this infinite-loop so that when it reaches the end of the file it exits the loop. Also, I am not entirely sure if the fread is doing what I expect it to.

```
 FILE *fptr = fopen("number.db", "wb");
 int nums[100] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,100,101,102,103,104,105};
 int nums2[100];

 fwrite(nums,sizeof(int),15,fptr);
 fclose(fptr);

 fptr = fopen("number.db", "rb");
  fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_END);
  long end = ftell(fptr); //finds length of the file
  fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_SET);

 while(!feof(fptr)){
   int counter = 0;
   fread(nums2,sizeof(int),1,fptr);
   fseek(fptr,counter,SEEK_SET);
   counter++;
   if(counter>=end){ //Breaks when it seeks to the end
      break;
    }
 fclose(fptr);
```

I feel like there is something with the logic of the fread, however I am not too sure. When I print out the numbers that are saves in "nums2" its only the last number that is read: 105 for all elements of nums2.

Comment: This is infinite loop because you are initializing `counter` to 0 every time in the loop and `fseek` taking the pointer to the beginning of the file. Take out `int counter = 0;` outside your loop

Comment: and `fread(nums2,sizeof(int),1,fptr);` --> `fread(nums2+counter, sizeof(int),1,fptr);` , Need `end /= sizeof(int);`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the combination of the seek/counter initialization.

If you set every time the counter to 0 (first record) and the you seek for it, you will always be in a "valid range" in the file records. The end of file condition will never occur, hence, the while look will enter an infinite loop

I do believe that the if condition "if(counter>=end)" is useless as well, I would remove it. The while loop will complete once eof, this is the way it should be.

```
 FILE *fptr = fopen("number.db", "wb");
 int nums[100] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,100,101,102,103,104,105};
 int nums2[100];

 fwrite(nums,sizeof(int),15,fptr);
 fclose(fptr);

 fptr = fopen("number.db", "rb");
 fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_END);
 long end = ftell(fptr); //finds length of the file
 fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_SET);
 int counter = 0;
 while(!feof(fptr)){
      fread(nums2,sizeof(int),1,fptr);
      fseek(fptr,counter,SEEK_SET);
      counter++;
      if(counter>=end){ //Breaks when it seeks to the end
           break;
      }
 }
 fclose(fptr);
```